# Select row and element in awk

Tags: awk

I learned that in awk, `$2` is the 2nd column. How to specify the ith line and the element at the ith row and jth column?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

To print the second line:

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print}'
```

To print the second field:

```
awk '{print $2}'
```

To print the third field of the fifth line:

```
awk 'FNR == 5 {print $3}'
```

Here's an example with a header line and (redundant) field descriptions:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Name\t\tAge"}  FNR == 5 {print "Name: "$3"\tAge: "$2}'
```

There are better ways to align columns than "\t\t" by the way.

Use `exit` to stop as soon as you've printed the desired record if there's no reason to process the whole file:

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print; exit}'
```

Answer (score 29):

To print the columns with a specific string, you use the // search pattern. For example, if you are looking for second columns that contains abc:

```
awk '$2 ~ /abc/'
```

... and if you want to print only a particular column:

```
awk '$2 ~ /abc/ { print $3 }'
```

... and for a particular line number:

```
awk '$2 ~ /abc/ && FNR == 5 { print $3 }'
```

Answer (score 26):

To expand on Dennis's answer, use `awk`'s `-v` option to pass the `i` and `j` values:

```
# print the j'th field of the i'th line
awk -v i=5 -v j=3 'FNR == i {print $j}'
```

Comment: May we have an example of when using the -v option would be helpful?

Comment: @dessert the `j` is filled in with the value `3`, so when it does `print $j` it's doing `print $3` which is printing the third column, so it is correct as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

Since awk and perl are closely related...

---

Perl equivalents of @Dennis's awk solutions:

To print the second line:
`perl -ne 'print if $. == 2' file`

To print the second field:
`perl -lane 'print $F[1]' file`

To print the third field of the fifth line:
`perl -lane 'print $F[2] if $. == 5' file`

---

Perl equivalent of @Glenn's solution:

Print the j'th field of the i'th line

`perl -lanse 'print $F[$j-1] if $. == $i' -- -i=5 -j=3 file`

---

Perl equivalents of @Hai's solutions:

if you are looking for second columns that contains abc:

`perl -lane 'print if $F[1] =~ /abc/' foo`

... and if you want to print only a particular column:

`perl -lane 'print $F[2] if $F[1] =~ /abc/' foo`

... and for a particular line number:

`perl -lane 'print $F[2] if $F[1] =~ /abc/ && $. == 5' foo`

---

`-l` removes newlines, and adds them back in when printing
`-a` autosplits the input line into array `@F`, using whitespace as the delimiter
`-n` loop over each line of the input file
`-e` execute the code within quotes
`$F[1]` is the second element of the array, since Perl starts at `0`
`$.` is the line number