# Get the YAML path of a given line in a file

Tags: yaml, yq

Using yq (or any other tool), how can I return the full YAML path of an arbitrary line number ?

e.g. with this file :

```yaml
a:
  b:
    c: "foo"
  d: |
    abc
    def
```

I want to get the full path of line 2; it should yield: `a.b.c`. Line 0 ? `a`, Line 4 ? `a.d` (multiline support), etc.

Any idea how I could achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: line number need not be an accurate representation in a grammar that supports new lines (e.g. in YAML), e.g. what if there are empty lines between each of the fields?

Comment: In this context, we don't care. Given a specific line, it should deduce the current key and then the full path. I'll amend with a multiline example.

Answer (score 1):

I have coded two solutions that differ slightly in their behaviour (see remarks below)

Use the YAML processor [mikefarah/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/).

I have also tried to solve the problem using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), but it is not suitable,
because the operator `input_line_number` only works in combination with the `--raw-input` option

### Version 1

```bash
FILE='sample.yml'
export LINE=1
yq e '[..
       | select(line == env(LINE))
       | {"line": line,
          "path": path | join("."),
          "type": type,
          "value": .}
      ]' $FILE
```

**Remarks**

- `LINE=3` returns two results, because line 3 contains two nodes

  1. the key 'c' of map 'a.b'
  2. the string value 'foo' of key 'c'.
- `LINE=5` does not return a match, because the multiline text node starts in line 4.
- the results are wrapped in an array, as multiple nodes can be returned

**Output for `LINE=1`**

```yaml
- line: 1
  path: ""
  type: '!!map'
  value:
    a:
      b:
        c: "foo"
    d: |-
      abc
      def
```

**Output for `LINE=2`**

```yaml
- line: 2
  path: a
  type: '!!map'
  value:
    b:
      c: "foo"
```

**Output for `LINE=3`**

```yaml
- line: 3
  path: a.b
  type: '!!map'
  value:
    c: "foo"
- line: 3
  path: a.b.c
  type: '!!str'
  value: "foo"
```

**Output for `LINE=4`**

```yaml
- line: 4
  path: d
  type: '!!str'
  value: |-
    abc
    def
```

**Output for `LINE=5`**

```yaml
[]
```

### Version 2

```bash
FILE='sample.yml'
export LINE=1
if [[ $(wc -l < $FILE) -lt $LINE ]]; then
  echo "$FILE has less than $LINE lines"
  exit
fi
yq e '[..
       | select(line <= env(LINE))
       | {"line": line,
          "path": path | join("."),
          "type": type,
          "value": .}
      ]
      | sort_by(.line, .type)
      | .[-1]' $FILE
```

**Remarks**

- at most one node is returned, even if there are more nodes in the selected row. So the result does not have to be wrapped in an array.
  Which node of one line is returned can be controlled by the `sort_by` function, which can be adapted to your own needs.
  In this case, text nodes are preferred over maps because "!!map" is sorted before "!!str".
- `LINE=3` returns only the text node of line 3 (not node of type "!!map")
- `LINE=5` returns the multiline text node starting at line 4
- `LINE=99` does not return the last multiline text node of `sample.yaml` because the maximum number of lines is checked in bash beforehand

**Output for `LINE=1`**

```yaml
line: 1
path: ""
type: '!!map'
value:
  a:
    b:
      c: "foo"
  d: |-
    abc
    def
```

**Output for `LINE=2`**

```yaml
line: 2
path: a
type: '!!map'
value:
  b:
    c: "foo"
```

**Output for `LINE=3`**

```yaml
line: 3
path: a.b.c
type: '!!str'
value: "foo"
```

**Output for `LINE=4`**

```yaml
line: 4
path: d
type: '!!str'
value: |-
  abc
  def
```

**Output for `LINE=5`**

```yaml
line: 4
path: d
type: '!!str'
value: |-
  abc
  def
```

Comment: Thanks, but indeed I need this one parameter.

Comment: I have come up with a robust solution for you that includes a 'LINE' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my findings since I've spent too much time on this.

---

As [@Inian mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74318108/get-the-yaml-path-of-a-given-line-in-a-file#comment131204279_74318108) line numbers won't necessary be accurate.

YQ does provides us with the [`line`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74318108/get-the-yaml-path-of-a-given-line-in-a-file#comment131204279_74318108) operator, but I was not able to find a decent way of mapping that from an input.

---

That said, if you're sure the input file will not contain any multi-line values, you could do something like this

1. Use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to get the `key` of your input line, eg `3 --> C`
   <sub>This assumes the value will never contain `:`, the regex can be edited if needed to go around this</sub>

   - [Select row in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506521/select-row-and-element-in-awk)
   - [Trim leading and trailing spaces from a string in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600982/trim-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string-in-awk)

   ```bash
   export searchKey=$(awk -F':' 'FNR == 3 { gsub(/ /,""); print $1 }' ii)
   ```
2. Use `YQ` to recursive ([`..`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/recursive-descent-glob)) loop over the values, and create each path using (`path | join(".")`)

   ```bash
   yq e '.. | (path | join("."))' ii
   ```
3. Filter the values from step 2, using a regex where we only want those path's that end in the key from step 1 (`strenv(searchKey)`)

   ```bash
   yq e '.. | (path | join(".")) | select(match(strenv(searchKey) + "$"))' ii
   ```
4. Print the path if it's found

---

Some examples from my local machine, where your input file is named `ii` and both `awk` + `yq` commands are wrapped in a bash function

```bash
$ function getPathByLineNumber () {
    key=$1
    export searchKey="$(awk  -v key=$key -F':' 'FNR == key { gsub(/ /, ""); print $1 }' ii)"
    yq e '.. | (path | join(".")) | select(match(strenv(searchKey) + "$"))' ii
}
$
$
$
$
$ yq e . ii
a:
  b:
    c: "foo"
$
$
$ getPathByLineNumber 1
a
$ getPathByLineNumber 2
a.b
$ getPathByLineNumber 3
a.b.c
$
$
```